# API response return different structure cause conversion error

Tags: spring-boot, feign, openfeign

I have this json response back from API:

With result:

```
{
  "Result": {"name":"Jason"},
  "Status": 1
}
```

Without result:

```
{
  "Result": "Not found",
  "Status": 1
}
```

As you can see the format the different.

When using Feign when not found I will certainly hit the conversion error:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseDto sendRequest(@RequestParam("id") String ID);
}
```

Any way to resolve this without changing the API?
I will certainly hit with an error

```
Cannot construct instance of `com.clients.dto.ResponseDto` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Not found.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generics to solve the issue.

```
public class ResponseDto<T>{

private T Result;
private Long Status;

...getters and setters....

}
```

maybe create model for another class as well:

```
public class SuccessResult{

private String name;

...getters and setters....

}
```

Now in Feign:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public <T> ResponseDto<T> sendRequest(@RequestParam("id") String ID);
}
```

**OR....**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseDto<?> sendRequest(@RequestParam("id") String ID);
}
```

After you get the response use object mapper to convert the value:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

.....

@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

//....your method and logic...

ResponseDto responseDto = sendRequest("1");

String res = null;
String successResponse = null;


if(responseDto.getResult() instanceof String)
{
    res = objectMapper.convert(responseDto.getResult(), String.class);

} else{

    successResponse = objectMapper.convert(responseDto.getResult(), SuccessResult.class);

}
```

Comment: Two corrections in the last code part, ---- ResponseDto<?> responseDto = sendRequest("1"); -/instead of/- ResponseDto responseDto = sendRequest("1"); === and === SuccessResult successResponse = null; -/ instead of /- String successResponse = null; ---in the last code part.